# JQ Transverse List as Map

Tags: json, jq

I want to convert the Below JSON to Map. but its coming as a list.

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "items": [
      {
         "order": 1,
        "technical": {
          "id": 1,
          "_links": {
            "self": {
              "href": "/profile/api/v3/service/40/technical"
            }
          }
        }
      },
       {
        "order": 2,
        "technical": {
          "id": 1,
          "_links": {
            "self": {
              "href": "/profile/api/v3/service/40/technical"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Expected format:

```
{
  "1": "/profile/api/v3/service/40/technical",
  "2": "/profile/api/v3/service/40/technical"
}
```

But i am getting :::

```
[
  {
    "1": "/profile/api/v3/service/40/technical"
  },
  {
    "2": "/profile/api/v3/service/40/technical"
  }
]
```

JQ Query:::

```
._embedded.items | map({(.order| tostring ) : .technical._links.self.href} )
```

Please help, Thanks in Advance..

Code Snippet - https://jqplay.org/s/cEzh5_LimP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply tack on `| add` to the end of your jq program.